# Web service deploying issue in WebLogic 10.3

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, jax-ws, soapheader

I have created a web service using MyEclipse 10.0 and it's working fine on Tomcat 6.0, but when I'm deploying it on WebLogic I'm getting exception.

I'm using `SoapHeader`, I'm adding header elements on it. My program in WebLogic is getting stuck when it's trying to add `SoapHeader` element to it.

```
SoapHeader header = envelope.getheader();
SoapHeaderElement element;
element = addheaderelement(new QName(namespace, "OTAuthentication");
```

I don't know what I m doing wrong here, it's able to add with Tomcat server, but not able to do in WebLogic 10.3.6

The war file is able to deploy, but while calling the method, it stops here and throws exception

```
Fault<UNIMPLEMENTED>Fault
Java.XML.soapheaderfault
```

Answer (score 1):

Well your problem might be related that you developed via Axis or Apache CXF your webservice.

Weblogic is using it's own implementation based on Metro